# Memory leak in IWbemServices->ExecNotificationQuery?

Tags: c++, winapi, memory-leaks, wmi, wmi-query

I have a WMI-related code, that gets an event, once new app is started.
I've skipped initialization part, here is the code. Note, that everything is working, all HRESULTs are S_OK.

```
IEnumWbemClassObject* pEnumerator = NULL;

pSvc->ExecNotificationQuery( // IWbemServices *pSvc is initialized
    bstr_t("WQL"),
    bstr_t("SELECT * FROM __InstanceCreationEvent WITHIN 1 "
        "WHERE TargetInstance ISA 'Win32_Process'"),
    WBEM_FLAG_FORWARD_ONLY | WBEM_FLAG_RETURN_IMMEDIATELY,
    NULL, &pEnumerator);

while (pEnumerator) {
    _variant_t v1, v2;
    pclsObj->Get(_bstr_t(L"TargetInstance"), 0, &v1, 0, 0);
    IUnknown* str = v1;
    str->QueryInterface(IID_IWbemClassObject, reinterpret_cast< void** >(&pclsObj));
    pclsObj->Get(bstr_t(L"Handle"), 0, &v2, 0, 0);
    LONG pid{ 0 };
    hr = VarI4FromStr(v2.bstrVal, LOCALE_NOUSEROVERRIDE, 409, &pid);
    Internal::Inject(pid); // It's my code, not relevant here

    str->Release();
    pclsObj->Release();
    v1.Clear();
    v2.Clear();
}
```

This code was taken from MSDN and slightly modified. However, it leaks memory, and I have no idea why. Looking via MSVC memory profiler gives us this picture:
[image: screen1]

or this:
[image: screen2]

From my point of view - I've cleared\released everything, however, allocations, like on screenshots happens once new event arrive and they are staying forever.

I've found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39660728/memory-leak-in-wmi-ms-example-code), it appears to be the same, but no answer received.

Visual Studio 2015 Update 3, up-to-date Windows 10 x64 Professional.

Comment: Do you call the Release() on pEnumerator? It is also a COM object

Comment: @matt, i've tried, not helped

Comment: try this tool DebugDiag: https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=49924

Answer (score 1):

When you call `str->QueryInterface()`, you are overriding the `pclsObj` pointer without calling `pclsObj->Release()` beforehand. You are calling `Release()` on the `pclsObj` object that `QueryInterface()` returns, and leaking the original `pclsObj` object.

You should stop managing interface reference counts manually and use the `_com_ptr_t` wrapper instead.

Where is the original `pclsObj` coming from? It looks like you are missing a call to `pEnumerator->Next()`.

Try something more like this instead (error handling omitted for brevity):

```
_com_ptr_t<IEnumWbemClassObject> pEnumerator;

pSvc->ExecNotificationQuery( // IWbemServices *pSvc is initialized
    bstr_t("WQL"),
    bstr_t("SELECT * FROM __InstanceCreationEvent WITHIN 1 "
        "WHERE TargetInstance ISA 'Win32_Process'"),
    WBEM_FLAG_FORWARD_ONLY | WBEM_FLAG_RETURN_IMMEDIATELY,
    NULL, &pEnumerator);

if (pEnumerator)
{
    while (true)
    {
        _com_ptr_t<IWbemClassObject> pclsEvent, pclsObj;
        _variant_t v1, v2;
        ULONG ulReturned = 0;

        pEnumerator->Next(WBEM_INFINITE, 1, &pclsEvent, &ulReturned);
        pclsEvent->Get(_bstr_t(L"TargetInstance"), 0, &v1, 0, 0);

        _com_ptr_t<IUnknown> str = v1;
        str->QueryInterface(IID_IWbemClassObject, reinterpret_cast<void**>(&pclsObj));
        pclsObj->Get(bstr_t(L"Handle"), 0, &v2, 0, 0);

        LONG pid{ 0 };
        hr = VarI4FromStr(v2.bstrVal, LOCALE_NOUSEROVERRIDE, 409, &pid);
        Internal::Inject(pid); // It's my code, not relevant here
    }
}
```

Alternatively:

```
_com_ptr_t<IEnumWbemClassObject> pEnumerator;

pSvc->ExecNotificationQuery( // IWbemServices *pSvc is initialized
    bstr_t("WQL"),
    bstr_t("SELECT * FROM __InstanceCreationEvent WITHIN 1 "
        "WHERE TargetInstance ISA 'Win32_Process'"),
    WBEM_FLAG_FORWARD_ONLY | WBEM_FLAG_RETURN_IMMEDIATELY,
    NULL, &pEnumerator);

if (pEnumerator)
{
    while (true)
    {
        _com_ptr_t<IWbemClassObject> pclsObj;
        _variant_t v1, v2;
        ULONG ulReturned = 0;

        pEnumerator->Next(WBEM_INFINITE, 1, &pclsObj, &ulReturned);
        pclsObj->Get(_bstr_t(L"TargetInstance"), 0, &v1, 0, 0);

        // _com_ptr_t::operator&() calls Release() on the current object
        // if not NULL before then returning the address of the the
        // interface pointer...

        _com_ptr_t<IUnknown> str = v1;
        str->QueryInterface(IID_IWbemClassObject, reinterpret_cast<void**>(&pclsObj));
        pclsObj->Get(bstr_t(L"Handle"), 0, &v2, 0, 0);

        LONG pid{ 0 };
        hr = VarI4FromStr(v2.bstrVal, LOCALE_NOUSEROVERRIDE, 409, &pid);
        Internal::Inject(pid); // It's my code, not relevant here
    }
}
```

Comment: There's also the handy [IID_PPV_ARGS](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ee330727.aspx) macro, that allows you to write: `str->QueryInterface( IID_PPV_ARGS( &pclsObj ) );`. It's not only shorter, it's also safer, since interface ID and pointer type are guaranteed to match.

Comment: Can you explain a bit VarI4FromStr ? I tried the same thing but I get some in-existent pid..

Comment: @NorbertBoros Did you read the documentation yet? [VarI4FromStr function](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/ms221194) and [Win32_Process class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/cimwin32prov/win32-process). In the `__InstanceCreationEvent` events being queried, the `TargetInstance` is a `Win32_Process` object, and its `Handle` property is a `string` (which is a [`BSTR`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/desktop/automat/bstr) in COM). `VarI4FromStr()` simply converts a string to an integer.

Comment: Yep I did after I commented... my bad :) Thanks anyway